# Como saber se um list está vazio em Python?

Tags: python, lista

Estou iniciando no `python` e sempre acabam surgindo algumas dúvidas no início.

Preciso saber como testar se uma `list` está vazia.

Como sempre costumo dizer, venho do PHP.

Então eu costumava a fazer dessas formas:

```
count($array) == 0

empty($array);

!$array
```

Como fazer isso em `python`?

Exemplo:

```
 a = [1, 2, 3]
 b = []

 # a é vazio?
 # b é vazio?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suponho `a` uma lista:

```
a = []
```

Testa-se assim:

```
if not a:
    # Condição se for vazio.
```

Sim. Muito simples.

Comment: +1. Muito, muito simples mesmo!

Comment: Adicionando, "if not" é executado quando o valor for zero, vazio ou false.

Answer (score 4):

Apenas para fins de curiosidade. Você também pode fazer do "jeito feio".

Ainda supondo que `a` é uma lista

`a = []`

```
if len(a) == 0:
    # Condição se for vazio

if a == []:
    # Condição ser for vazio
```

Comment: +1 pelo jeito feio de ser. Não é muito comum no Python, mas é familiar no PHP

Comment: Bleh. Tosqueira.

Comment: Pensei que o impacto seria menor, já que ele programa em PHP @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: @jbueno Pensa na qualidade de vida, jovem.